# Check if arrow keys or escape is pressed - nonblocking

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, stdin

I'm using this code to check if the user has pressed an arrow key. It works just fine. Now I'd also like to check if the Escape key was pressed. I'll just assume that if it's not an arrow key, it must be the Escape key.

It sort of works, the problem is that while the arrow keys contains 3 characters, the Escape key is only 1 character. This means you have to press the Escape key multiple times before getting a response.

```
import sys
import select
import tty
import termios
from time import sleep

def is_key_pressed():
    return select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0) == ([sys.stdin], [], [])

def reset_terminal(old_settings):
    termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)


old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
try:
    tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())

    while True:

        if is_key_pressed():
            char = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
            if char == 27:
                ch = ord(sys.stdin.read(2)[1])
                if ch in [65, 66, 67, 68]:
                    print("Arrow pressed")
                    continue

                print("Escape pressed")

        sleep(0.1)

finally:
    reset_terminal(old_settings)
```

I tried doing a reset just before printing "Escape pressed", but it didn't work.

Comment: It is printing Escape pressed it's just taking it's time... (it looks like there is some kind of lag in your code)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73122437/6013016) must help