# Python, check if arrow key pressed

Tags: python, click, user-input

How to check if user presses an arrow key in python? I want something like this:

```
if right_key.pressed():
    do_some_shit()
elif left_key.pressed():
    do_other_stuff()
```

*Update: I'm not using pygame, just need to detect key press*

Comment: If you are using `pygame` I recommend the use key events.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal (or anacoonda prompt) run this command to install pynput `library`:

```
pip install pynput
```

And, in your editor

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key

def on_key_release(key):
    if key == Key.right:
        print("Right key clicked")
    elif key == Key.left:
        print("Left key clicked")
    elif key == Key.up:
        print("Up key clicked")
    elif key == Key.down:
        print("Down key clicked")
    elif key == Key.esc:
        exit()


with keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_key_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

[More info](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard)

Comment: This worked for me except I had to replace "exit()" with "return False".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
import keyboard
import time

while True:
   try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('left'):
            print('You Pressed left!')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('right'):
            print('You Pressed right!')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('down'):
            print('You Pressed down!')
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('up'):
            print('You Pressed up!')
        time.sleep(0.1)

    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

By using listeners you will not have to play an infinite loop. Which I think is more elegant. This code will help you:

```
from pynput import keyboard
    
def on_press(key):
        if key == keyboard.Key.up:
            print('PRESSED')
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            listener.stop()
    
    
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Note that with 'keyboard.Key' you can detect the key that you want. You can even reproduce the case of holding two keys at the same time and detecting a combination!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I made, but it's only for a Pygame project with a window
If you need the arrows in pygame I recommend this code:

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import sys

window_height = 100
window_width = 100

window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
# This is the code to check if a player is pushing the arrows

while True:
    for evenement in pygame.event.get():
        if evenement.type == QUIT or (evenement.type == KEYDOWN and 
                                      evenement.key == K_ESCAPE):
            print('QUIT')
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if evenement.type == KEYDOWN and evenement.key == K_RIGHT:
            print("Clicked on the right arrow")
        if evenement.type == KEYDOWN and evenement.key == K_LEFT:
            print("Clicked on the left arrow")
        if evenement.type == KEYDOWN and evenement.key == K_UP:
            print("Clicked on the up arrow")
        if evenement.type == KEYDOWN and evenement.key == K_DOWN:
            print("Clicked on the down arrow")
```